# List<Character> how to get specific index?

Tags: java, list, position

How can I get a specific index in the List if it has only the methods for the first and last element, when the element in the list repeats several times?

```
List<Character> listString = new ArrayList<>();

listString.add(0, 'A');
listString.add(1, 'A');
listString.add(2, 'A');
listString.add(3, 'A');


int index = listString.indexOf('A');
int indexLast = listString.lastIndexOf('A');

System.out.println(index);
System.out.println(indexLast);
```

Output:

> 0
>
> 3

So how can I get information that 'A' is also in index 1 and 2?

Comment: Well you can use `List.get` to check the value at any index...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a typical for loop:

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < listString.size(); i++) 
     if(listString.get(i) == 'A')
        indices.add(i);
```

or:

```
int[] indices = IntStream.range(0, listString.size())
                         .filter(i -> listString.get(i) == 'A')
                         .toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

You can print your answers out like this (after writing the above code):

```
for (int i = 0; i <indices.size() ; i++) {
        System.out.println(indices.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help